# SQL: How to design best table for my data structure

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I am designing postgresql database for an online card game. I want to provide users with option to access their play history - user can see log of his games.

The data I want to save has the following structure:

```
Player Ids | game_data
-----------|--------------
A,B,C,D    | ..game log..
A,D,E,F    | ..game log..
D,C,A      | ..game log..
D,A        | ..game log..
```

Each game can have up to 22 participants, so Max number of players is 22, Min number of players is 2.

So far I have about 100M records. Every day I add about 500K records. I have about 500K Players. Player-ID is a 32 byte string (MD5).

I want players to be able to access their game_data, so I want player to be able to select last XX games_logs by Player-Id. I need to do it as fast as possible. What would be the best way to do it with Postgres? I would prefer to save all these data in a single table.

So far I am considering two approaches:

### Approach 1

Make a field of JSON type and save all Player's in in JSON-Array and query JSON in SELCT statment.

### Approach 2

Make 22 fields in a table for each player (If there is no player field is NULL) and make ugly query over all fields.

So far I don't like any of these approaches. If there is a better way to do it?

### Added

Typical request would be: SELECT LAST XXX GAME FOR PLAYER_ID = 'A'

Comment: Do combination of keys correspond to a json_data or each key corresponds to a json_data?

Comment: Each key corresponds to a json_data. There is no such a think as a key combination. Every time it can be any keys.

Comment: Please specify more closely what that's supposed to mean: `access their game_data`. What exactly should a query return, in what form, sorted how?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, I added that player might be interested in most in last XXX of his games. Sorting and form of the data is not subject of my question.

Comment: @MaxB: You are asking for performance, so the sort order of multiple rows returned is relevant. Please define it.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I just added typical query. Further sorting is not relevant - I can do it in another subquery - my main question is - how to organize selection by Player-Id without extra tables. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 2):

A user can have many keys, and a key may belong to many user , that's why you should have third table to contain user-key pairs. You should kep json value of each key in keys table.

Here is how it should be.

[image]

Comment: We can think that KEY is a user ID. I need a postgresql technique to handle my select in a fast possible way.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a table with a serial field (just to follow the convention), an array of integers to store the keys and a json field to hold the data.

You can add indexes to array columns in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You will really regret Approach number 2.  It's hell to check every USER1...22 field for playerid = X when retrieving GameData per User.    I have seen it used many times in systems designed for easy data entry with little thought to getting the data out.  Your SQL or other code will be brittle and you will be loathe to write test code.

Do you really need to keep it to just one table?  The standard ('normalized') Many-to-many approach can be really fast with proper db indexing and tuning.   Use integer keys when possible.  Call that option #3 (e.g. make a many-to-many table GameUsers table  with two columns user_id and game_id)

I have a similar situation, and do BOTH #1 and the Many-to-Many tables.  For your solution #1,  instead of JSON I insert a delimited list of user names in a text field.   I just store these user_id's (which in my case are text, which I don't like either) as comma delimited (my customer likes commas) however I add preceding and ending commas like this:  ",A,D,E,F,"

The Simplistic SQL :

```
select game_log from game_data where user_list LIKE ('%,D,%')
```

or if user_id is variable or column

```
select game_log from game_data where user_list LIKE ('%,' || user_id || ',%')
```

You need both delimiters as user names can overlap (e.g. "Mirko" and "Mirkota") and you don't have to waste time checking for cases where its' at beginning or end of the list.  Of course you must use a delimiter not allowed in user ids, and make sure to strip out this delimiter (and other forbidden characters) from user input data to avoid SQL injection.

The big downside of doing both is keeping them in sync but given data in many-to-many tables (approach #3) you can re-generate the users list using [string_agg(expression, delimiter)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) and concat the extra delimiters

I don't think that Serial or "array" fields are not going to help here, even with positional indexing.  You still have to search each position in the array, and the vast majority of your 22-lenght arrays will be mostly empty.

In my case I am doing social network analysis so I need to know when users are together and using multiple LIKE conditions is faster than multiple joins.

Comment: your approach with LIKE seems to work, but I have to check performance first. Thank you for your input!